# iTerm Startup with Commands

Tags: macos, iterm

I was wondering if it is possible to have iTerm startup with commands to run? For example, I have a default saved layout with 4 panes. One of them I have to startup mySql and in another I have to start up Mongo. I was wondering if it is possible to have these startup as soon as I open iTerm? I know these can be started up in other ways, just wondering if this can be done with iTerm?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In prefs>general, you can tell it to open the default saved arrangement at startup.